# How can I redirect a file with the same name to a different directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've recently moved my site that is nearly 1 to 1 in respect to the urls and sources. However, one set of files that were in the `http://oldurl.com/file/` directory are now in a strucutre like `http://newurl.com/sitefiles/jan/2016/`. The names haven't changed just the location.

I can I 301 redirect the entire location **up to** the filename itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/file/ /sitefiles/jan/2016
```